# What does << mean in Java?

Tags: java, operators

I can't find out what `<<` means in Java because I can't search for it on Google - I am absolutely lost!

The code in question is:

```
public int getRGB() {
    return ((red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue);
}
```

It's taken from: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/example/ImmutableRGB.java

I would really appreciate someone telling me, thanks!

Comment: Good idea. Let's see: Google responds with "Your search - << - did not match any documents."

Comment: Google strips most (maybe all?) symbols of a search, even if you apply + or "" operators. I imagine it's to save resources.

Comment: as noted in some answers below, a liitle reasoning before searching does the trick

Comment: Also, from Joel Spolsky: "No matter how easy the newbie question is, it's legit on Stack Overflow."

Comment: <http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+%3C%3C&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8> -> Did you mean:  "java << operator", and the first hit is the java operators page <http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html> … so why can't you search for this on Google?

Comment: @htw, that's right. We are just giving directions on how to answer questions more quickly _next time_

Comment: In response to Paul Wagland, that is what I searched initially. Following your link the suggestion comes up, but for some reason it didn't when I used google.co.nz ( http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=java+%3C%3C )

Comment: Downvote: It's newbie question on Google and not java

Comment: I used &lt;&lt; to find this question.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Left shift of the bits

If red == 4 (which in binary is: 00000100) then red << 16 will insert sixteen 0-bits at its right, yielding: 000001000000000000000000 which is 262144 in decimal

Answer (score 30):

Q. What is this? 
A. An "operator"

Q. How do I get to know about operators in java?
A. Google for "Java operators"

And the result is [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

> The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left, and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand. The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

Comment: Kudos for teaching him how to fish instead of giving the man a fish.

Answer (score 8):

Left shift a number of bits. It is equivalent to multiplying by two that many times.

It's used for setting specific bits in a byte, or specific bytes in a word.

Answer (score 3):

It is the left shift operator.  Here's some more information on shift operators from the [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

In your example code the three integer values: red, green and blue will typically have values 0-255.  Hence, it is possible to combine these values and represent them as a single integer by shifting the red value by 16 bits, shifting the green value by 8 bits and then performing a bitwise-OR operation to combine the values.

Answer (score 2):

its a bit shift. search for `operators java`, it will return you detailed explanations.

Answer (score 2):

"<<" means left shift the bits of a value.
">>" means right shift the bits of a value.

example:
int a = 5; //the binary value of 5 is 101
a = a << 3; //left shift 3 bits on 101, 101 000<< add 3 bits(0) on the right, become '101000'
System.out.println(a); //this will display 40, the decimal for '101000'

int b = 9; //the binary value of 8 is 1001
b = b >> 3; //right shift 3 bits on >>000 1<strike>001</strike> add 3 bits(0) on the left, truncate the last 3 bits on the right become '001'
System.out.println(b); //this will display 1, the decimal for '001'

Answer (score 1):

Its a left bit shift

Answer (score 1):

Its left shifting and convert Red, Green, Blue into 24 bit Number